# how to get json objects attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Beginner at both JSON and javascript. I need a way to return the **key** `subAttributeOne` it self from a list of object instead of his value.

Following is example of a list,

```
var list = 
[
   {
   attribute1: "value",
   attribute2:[{subAttributeOne:"value",subAttributeTwo:"value"},{}]
   },
   //other objects
   {..}
]
```

I have tried following,

```
list[0].attribute2[1].subAttributeOne
```

it returns `value` but the result I need is `subAttributeOne`

Comment: Err… You already know you're looking for the string `"subAttributeOne"`… so what's there to look up in the array? It's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: USE Object.keys(list[0].attribute2[0]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want keys from an object you can use `object.keys` that will bring back all the keys, but to define its position, in your case you can use like below:

```
Object.keys(list[0].attribute2[1])[0]
```

But the `[0]` doesn't work like an index because properties order in objects is not guarantee in JavaScript.
To learn more about this I recommand you to read about :  [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

In this link you will find the definition of an Object from ECMAScript Third Edition:

> 4.3.3 Object
>
> An object is a member of the type Object. It is an **unordered
>   collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive value,
>   object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is
>   called a method

Comment: This working only because `subAttributeTwo` is bigger then `subAttributeOne`. The order of the keys is alphabetically

Comment: @t.gian18 The order is *arbitrary*, i.e. there is none.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Answer (score 5):

With this:

```
Object.keys(list[0].attribute2[0])
```

you get

```
['subAttributeOne', 'subAttributeTwo']
```